# PHP Simple For loop only loop today's date with time function

Tags: php

I need to write a simple php code that decrements day by day and stop when a certain date hits (in this case yesterday). I have written following code piece to do this but this seems to be looping forever ... not stooping at the forloop break condition i set

```
//start time to decrements
$time = time(); // for now start with today or set with strtotime('2010-08-01 00:00:00');
for ($time = time(); $time >= ($time - (24 * 3600)); $time = ($time - (24 * 3600))) {
    run("www.xyx.com",date("Y/m/d", $time));
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: code that decrements what?

Comment: try with counting the day of year 
date('z')
date('z', strtotime('+30 days'));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$time >= ($time - (24 * 3600))` is always going to be true. It is the same as saying

```
n >= n - 1
```

which is self-evidently true for all n.

Write it like this instead:

```
$end_time = time() - (24 * 3600);    // yesterday
for ($time = time(); $time >= $end_time; $time = ($time - (24 * 3600))) {
    run("www.xyx.com",date("Y/m/d", $time));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your use of the time() function from within the for loop. Try setting the start and stop variables before the loop.

```
//start time to decrements
$starttime = time(); // for now start with today or set with strtotime('2010-08-01 00:00:00');
$stoptime = $starttime - (24*3600);
for ($time = $starttime; $time >= $stoptime; $time = ($time - (24 * 3600))) {
    //echo date("Y/m/d", $time) . "\n";
    run("www.xyx.com",date("Y/m/d", $time));
}
```